# Main.storyboard showing black screen

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode-storyboard

I created an Xcode ios project. I choose the SwiftUI for the user interface. At a later stage, I decided to use Storyboard instead.

1. So created a new storyboard.
2. Added View Controller as an initial view controller
3. Changed the SceneDeligate scent to return  `guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }` instead of SwiftUI instance creation code.
4. Added `Main` in Info.plist as the Main storyboard.

When I run the app after above changes black screen appears after showing launch screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When working with Scenes, you need to specify the starting storyboard in a different place in the `Info.plist`, under

- *Application Scene Manifest*

  - *Scene Configuration*

    - *Application Session Role*

      - *Item 0*

        - *Storyboard Name* (this key needs to be added manually)

Unfortunately, this can only be done directly by editing the Info.plist, not in the target settings / deployment info section:

[image: Info.plist]

And don't forget to set the initial view controller in the storyboard:

[image: IsInitialViewController]

Comment: Your solution worked when I ran the app on the simulator. I am getting a blank screen when I ran it on the device.

Comment: Strange. Maybe you need to remove the app from the device and make a clean build.

Comment: work for me when I checked is Initial Controller. I'm getting a black screen.
thanks